# blender "Align selected light to view"? Similar to Maya

Tags: light

Blender 2.82 Is there an equivelent to "Align selected light to view"? 
Similar to how Maya allows to look through a light to focus on the object.
If not, what are the steps to to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+Num0</kbd> let you do that (kinda) :

<kbd>Ctrl+Num0</kbd> set the active object (may it be a light, a mesh or whatever) as the active camera, then automatically switch to camera view. So, it do what you want to do.

**But**, don't forget that this object is now considered the active camera! So you need to select the preexisting camera and press <kbd>Ctrl+Num0</kbd> again to come back to normal.

Comment: Oh, this is cool :). I never realized I can set a light as a camera.

Comment: Any object can be a camera! The only case where I found that to be useful is with a Spot Light, because the focal of the "camera" matches the size of the light cone. You can use it to bake a shadow map, or do fun stuffs like projection mapping.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the tip :). Just tried it with the spot light and it works surprisingly well.